# Pointer Wrapper: dereference operator

Tags: c++, .net, pointers, c++-cli

I'm pretty new to C++ and as an exercise (and perhaps eventually .Net utility) I'm doing a pointer wrapper (actually in C++/CLI, but this applies to C++ as well). This pointer wrapper (called `Apont`) currently behaves just like a pointer would, as the test below can show, if lines marked **1.** and **2.** are commented out:

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    double ia = 10; double ip = 10;
    double *p = &ip;                // pointer analogy
    Apont<double> ^a =
        gcnew Apont<double>(ia);    // equivalent to what's below, without errors
    a = ~ia;/* 1.       IntelliSense: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type
                        error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'double' to 'Utilidades::ComNativos::Apont<T> ^'
                        error C2171: '~' : illegal on operands of type 'double'*/
    Console::WriteLine("ip = {0}; *p = {1}; ia = {2}; !a = {3}", ip, *p, ia, !a);
    ia = 20; ip = 20;
    Console::WriteLine("ip = {0}; *p = {1}; ia = {2}; !a = {3}", ip, *p, ia, !a);
    *p = 30;        // pointer analogy
    a->Valor = 30;  // does exacly what's below, without errors
    !a = 30;/* 2.   IntelliSense: expression must be a modifiable lvalue
                    error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value */
    Console::WriteLine("ip = {0}; *p = {1}; ia = {2}; !a = {3}", ip, *p, ia, !a);
    //a->Dispose();
    Console::ReadKey();
    p = nullptr;
    return 0;
}
```

There are two things I don't like here, marked with **1.** and **2.** in the code comments, before the lines with errors. The `operator~` (see **1.**) is defined outside `Apont`, below:

```
template<typename T> static Apont<T>^% operator ~(T& valor)
{
    return gcnew Apont<T>(valor);
}
```

I think this one has to be defined outside `Apont`, but I'm not sure. I cannot understand very well the errors it produces (these are, of course, in the use, not in the definition).

To set the value to which the instance of `Apont` refers I must use a property (the line marked **2.** doesn't work, with errors in the setting usage only), `Apont::Valor`, which is the equivalent to use `*p`. What I'd like to do is as I use `*p` to get **or set** the value it points to, use `!a` with the same effect on `Apont`. Here's `Apont::operator!()`'s current definition:

```
T operator !()
{
    return Valor;
}
```

As you can see in **2.** (comment in the code, before the respective errors), it doesn't work for setting a value. Maybe I should return a reference? Make another operator with the same name, perhaps outside the class? I tried several options, however, I got similar errors, and came out more confused.

The question is: how can I make an operator that behaves like `&` (in this case, `~`) and one that behaves like `*` (in this case, `!`, for dereference, but that behaves like `Apont::Valor`, whose old definition you can see below)?

```
property T Valor
{
    T get()
    {
        if (pointer != nullptr)             
            return *pointer;
        else if (eliminado && ErroSeEliminado) // means "disposed && ErrorIfDisposed"
            throw gcnew ObjectDisposedException("O objeto já foi pelo menos parcialmente eliminadao.");
        else if (ErroSeNulo) // means "ErrorIfNull"
            throw gcnew NullReferenceException();
        else
            return 0;
// don't worry, this is not default behavior, it is returned only if you want to ignore all errors and if the pointer is null
    }
    void set(T valor)
    {
        *pointer = valor;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first error occurs because your definition of the operator `~` expects as argument a `T &`, but you pass a `const Apont<T>&`, which is why the compiler complains.

Comment: The for the second error, if you return by value, the return is not assignable, you need to return a reference instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me recap in a new answer for clarity.

Solving the `!` operator is easy, as I said in my previous answer, just add a reference.

So for the operator `~`, the goal was to have it behave like the `&` operator and call the constructor of the pointer wrapper class.

I don't think that is possible. It is certainly possible for user defined objects, but I don't think it is possible to overload unary operators for builtin types. So there are three solutions depending on what you prefer:

The first one does exactly what you want, but will break for primitive types:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct A {
    T* payload;

    A()
        : payload(NULL){}
    A(T *ptr)
        : payload(ptr) {}

    T& operator !(){
        return *payload;
    }
};

// this will not work for primary types
template<typename T>
A<T> operator ~(T &b){
    return A<T>(&b);
}

struct B{
    int test;
};

int main(){
    B b; b.test = 4;

    A<B> a;
    a = ~b; // I think this is what you want
    std::cerr << (!a).test << std::endl;

    // this does not work
    //int i = 4;
    //A<int> a;
    //a = ~i;
}
```

Second solution: use a compound assignment operator. Pros are the side effects are minimal, cons is this is not very intuitive and might break the nice design you had in mind.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct A {
    T* payload;

    A() : payload(NULL){}

    T& operator !(){
        return *payload;
    }
};

template<typename T>
A<T>& operator &=(A<T> &a, T& b){ // should be friend of the above
    a.payload = &b;
    return a;
}

int main(){
    int i = 3;
    A<int> a;
    a &= i;
    std::cerr << !a << std::endl;
}
```

Third solution: overload the basic assignment operator. This is more intuitive to write but has a lot of side effects:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct A {
    T* payload;

    A() : payload(NULL){}

    T& operator !(){
        return *payload;
    }

    A<T>& operator = (T & b) {
        payload = &b;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main(){
    int i = 3;
    A<int> a;
    a = i;
    std::cerr << !a << std::endl;
}
```

Someone might have a solution to hijack the operators for primitive types, but i can't think of any simple solution.

Comment: I got an idea using all three of your solutions: the second can be a stand-alone solution, and `B` can be a simple template container with implicit conversion to/from the type it contains and `operator~` to convert to `A`. I'll try this and mark your answer as soon as possible. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, if you wrap the object in a container class, you can define your own operators on it, but it requires an explicit wrap.

Comment: Why can't it be implicit wrapping?

Comment: if you want to preserve the syntax `A<int> a = ~i;` where i is a primitive type and the operator `~` is your own, then you will need to explicitly wrap the object to change the meaning of the operator. Something like ` A<int> a = ~B<int>(i)`. This might kill the purpose of using an operator in the first place.

Comment: I guess I'll use the second option then.

Comment: You can choose any other compound assignment operator if you want. I picked `&=` because it has `&` in it, which vaguely suggest the "taking the address of" you mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your code correctly, you want the operator `~` to return a copy of the pointer wrapper and the operator `!` to act as dereference?

In this case, you can define the unary `operator ~` inside the `Apont` class which calls a copy constructor. And the `operator !` has to return a reference indeed if you want to asign a value.

I think the following c++ code defines what you want to do (I renamed `Apont` to `A`):

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct A {
    T* payload;

    A(T *ptr)
        :payload(ptr) {}
    A(const A&other)
        :payload(other.payload) {}

    T& operator !(){
        return *payload;
    }

    T* operator ~(){
        return payload;
    }
};

int main(){
#define PRINT(X) std::cerr << #X << " = " << X << std::endl
    int i = 0;
    PRINT(i);

    A<int> a(&i);
    !a = 1;
    PRINT(i);

    A<int> b = ~a;
    !b = 2;
    PRINT(i);
}
```

The output of the code above is:

```
i = 0
i = 1
i = 2
```

According to your comments, you said you wanted the operator `!` to behave exactly like the wrapped pointer. You can do so, but then the syntax changes and you need to dereference it to assign a new value (because it is a pointer...). ie something like:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct A {
    T* payload;

    A(T *ptr): payload(ptr) {}

    // this now behaves like accessing the wrapped pointer directly
    T*& operator !(){
        return payload;
    }
};

int main(){
#define PRINT(X) std::cerr << #X << " = " << X << std::endl
    int i = 0;
    int j = 999;
    PRINT(i);

    A<int> a(&i);
    *(!a) = 1;  // note the change of syntax here
    PRINT(*!a); // and here

    !a = &j;    // but now you can change the wrapped pointer through the operator
    PRINT(*!a);
}
```

Comment: You're right about `operator!` (which does behave like `*`, although I wanted it to behave exactly like `Apont::Valor`), but I want `~` to behave like "take the address of" (`&`). Thanks for your time, +1, but I cannot mark this as answer, at least not yet.

Comment: I am not sure i understood this point. Is it doing what you want now?

Comment: `operator!` already was, but `operator~` isn't, because I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I have changed the return type of operator `~` in my original solution, this is still not what you want? What do you mean by "take the address of" then? the address of the wrapped pointer (`T**`), a copy of the pointer pointing on the same object (`T*`)? Could you give me a short usage example?

Comment: Notice: I don't want to directly expose the pointer, I want to have the pointer wrapped, yet have this class behave like a pointer. That is, `!a` dereferences the pointer that doesn't need to be known to exist, like your first `operator!` definition. `operator~` should behave like the "take the address of", that is, for example, `int i = 10; A<int> a = ~i; !a = 20;` and then `i == 20` should be true. `~i` should be of type `A<int>`, not `int *`.

Comment: Right, i think i got it. It might be possible with a compound assignment operator, but a unary operator might be pushing it. I'll get back to you in a minute.

Comment: it is not possible. Let me put that in a new answer.